# not send when the process failed

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have PHP code that help me to other people can be in touch with me and send their opinion to me .
here's my PHP code :

```
<?php

$to = 'ticket.ritaweb@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Your decision/Opinion';
$name = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['email']);
$site = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['site']);
$mobile = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mobile']);
$nazar = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['nazar']);
$sqt = '2164854';
$sqtin = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sqtin']);

if ($sqt === $sqtin) {

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-  
    type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message .= "name : " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "email : " . clean_string($email) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "address : " . clean_string($site) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "number : " . clean_string($mobile) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "opinion : " . clean_string($nazar) . "\n";
    $headers = 'From: ' . $mobile . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: 
    PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
?>
```

and I called it with javascript ( ajax ) but I want a code in ajax that help me If my condition in PHP file was FALSE or each of the field was empty , show the message : "Your message was not send, be careful".

 and here's my AJAX code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $('#submit').attr('value', 'sending...');
            $.post("themes/RitaWeb-v1/send.php", $(".rita_form").serialize(),
                    function(response) {
                        $('#submit').attr('value', 'sent.');
                    });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to print messages on the page, like

```
{'status' : 'success'}
```

if the mail was sent and

```
{'status' : 'error'}
```

Then do something based on the output with js.

**EDIT:**

If you use `jQuery.ajax` instead of `jQuery.post,`you can also use the settings argument to let something happen if there ared errors during the request.

More information: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

In your code, it would look like this.

PHP:

```
...

    mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);

    print('{"status":"success"}');
}

else{

    print('{"status":"error"}');
}
```

And your js:

```
$.ajax('themes/RitaWeb-v1/send.php').done(function(data){

    status = $.parseJSON(data).status;

    if(status == 'success'){
        // do something
    }

    else if(ststus == 'error'){
        // do something
    }

    else{
        alert('unknown response');
    }
});
```

Comment: @amn try the above. That's all i can do.